# OOP argument missing

Tags: python

I created this small program.  It should add to the cupboard some products. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: add_prod() missing 1 required positional argument: 'product'.
```

Here is the code:

```
class Products:

    def __init__(self,nome):
        self.nome = nome

class Cupboard:

    def __init__(self):
        self.prod = []
    def add_prod(self, product):
        self.prod.append(product)

    def show(self):
        print(self.prod)


p1 = Products("Ajax")
p2 = Products("Barilla")

Cupboard.add_prod(p1)
Cupboard.add_prod(p2)

show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code when you are trying to add `Products` to `Cupboard`, you are trying to do it to the class itself instead of to an instance.  You should create an instance of `Cupboard` first like you did for `Products`:

```
p1 = Products("Ajax")
p2 = Products("Barilla")

c1 = Cupboard()
c1.add_prod(p1)
c1.add_prod(p2)
```